# window.scrollBy And window.scrollTo is not working in edge..We used lazy loader from bakend for little scroll i used window.scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, lazy-loading

```
Scrollnavar() {
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('temple').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    window.scrollBy(0, 1);
                });
                document.getElementById('education').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    window.scrollBy(0, 2);
                });
            },
        },
```

<infinite-loading @distance="1" @infinite="getFilter">
this is the vue loader we used

I tried to add window.scrollTo but both are not working hp laptop.. why..?

Comment: You haven't shown any `scrollTo` example. But re your `scrollBy` examples: The parameter values are in **pixels**. It's really hard to see a one-pixel movement. (And if the page is scaled at all, you might not see it at all.)

Comment: This is less likely an issue with the lap and rather an issue with browser. Did you verify on other browsers in the same device?